# Order History notify

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, opencart, opencart2.x

I am very new to the Opencart, So please bear with me. My open cart is working properly as I needed but I am looking for small customization. When there is success payment, customer get confirmation email with order detail, bank transaction detail and shipping detail. But when order is cancel on payment transaction or payment decline than in confirmation email I am getting order detail, shipping detail **but not bank transaction detail**.

After digging to Opencart I found that my payment extension and order module is adding records in **order_history** three records in each record there is comment field where is payment transaction details which is coming from payment gateway like transaction id, reference id and transaction status etc. In the table there one field called notify value is **1** than that record will be added in Email.

So I want to know how can I make notify value to 1 for particular row of cancel and decline payment record in order_history

Code which I found in  /catalog/model/checkout/order.php

```
if ($comment && $notify) {
```

Comment: I can help yo but i did not understand what you want.

Comment: Hi Can we take to discussion. So I can explain more

Comment: ok you can create discussion

Comment: Sorry it looks like we cannot take to discussion.But I wanted to show you screen shot and explain

Comment: please add you screen shot in  your question

Comment: It is kind of complicated thing :(

Comment: Just show the images and tell me what you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162403/discussion-between-milind-and-amitesh-kumar).

Answer (score 1):

in `/catalog/model/checkout/order.php`

There is a method `addOrderHistory` in this method  below is query where you set the data in order history

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "order_history SET order_id = '" . (int) $order_id . "', order_status_id = '" . (int) $order_status_id . "', notify = '" . (int) $notify . "', comment = '" . $this->db->escape($comment) . "', date_added = NOW()");
```

For variable `$notify`   you have to send value 1 if your `$order_status_id` is  `10`

```
if($order_status_id == 10){
    $notify = 1;
}
```

This code should be above the query . And according to that you can change your email data  as you want.

My Suggestion is : Please maintain Different status for cancel order and decline payment. It will simplify you query.

Comment: I was thinking same but, if you see my image which I sent you in our discussion there are two row of status = 10 and I need last one not both. Hope you understand what I am telling

Comment: There will be a two solution 1. add another status for cancel , or just find the last insert status with 10 for that order, i think you can do that.

Comment: Let me try and get back to you

Comment: Hi after adding above code I am getting two emails. :(

Comment: Yes you will get two emails.

Comment: How can we stop that. Can we do same like success payment

Comment: For that check my answer i gave you the suggestion .

Comment: I could resolve the issue in payment gateway module I manage to get it worked :)